# Convert following SQL to JPQL

Tags: jpql

I have the following error. "Encountered "Count" at character 32, but expected: []."

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT m.title, COUNT(r.id) as Count FROM Movie m, Review r WHERE m.id = r.movie_id GROUP BY m.id, m.title;");

    Collection<Movie> result = (Collection<Movie>)query.getResultList();
```

Comment: So, is that SQL or JPQL? Don't use Count as alias, since it's a keyword. Don't end the query with a semi-colon.

Comment: That is my jpql

Comment: Thanks Count was the problem!